# Getting exact match record from a table

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table which have two columns trial_id , category_id

I am attaching the image so that it become more clear.

I want the records of trial_id which have category_id 260,2880 .

Ok for it I can run a query with "in" statement

something "SELECT * FROM `trial_category` WHERE category_id IN ( 260, 2880 )"[image]

it give trial_id as 73,213 but 73 has lot of other categories. So this should not display in result.

Result should contain only 213 trial_id or even I add another category_id in 213 then 213  should not show.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've got it right you need only trial_id's which contain only 260 or 2880 (both?)

```
SELECT * 
   FROM trial_category 
   WHERE category_id IN (260, 2880)
   and trial_id NOT IN (select trial_id 
                         from trial_category 
                         where category_id NOT IN (260, 2880))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    trial_category 
WHERE 
    category_id IN ( 260, 2880 ) 
    AND trial_id=213
```

And this will give you the `trial_id` for only those 2 categories:

```
SELECT 
    trial_id 
FROM 
    trial_category 
GROUP BY
    trial_id
HAVING
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT category_id ORDER BY category_id) = '260,2880'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT x.* 
   FROM trial_category x
   LEFT
   JOIN trial_category y
     ON y.trial_id = x.trial_id
    AND y.category_id NOT IN(260,2880)
  WHERE x.category_id IN (260,2880)
    AND y.id IS NULL;
```

?